# how to replace (or delete) a part of string from txt file in python

Tags: python, string

i am very new in python (and programming in general) and here is my issue. i would like to replace (or delete) a part of a string from a txt file which contains hundreds or thousands of lines. each line starts with the very same string which i want to delete.

i have not found a method to delete it so i tried a replace it with empty string but for some reason it doesn't work.

here is what i have written:

```
file = "C:/Users/experimental/Desktop/testfile siera.txt"
siera_log = open(file)

text_to_replace = "Chart: Bar Backtest: NQU8-CME [CB]  1 Min   #1 | Study: free dll = 0 |"

for each_line in siera_log:
     new_line = each_line.replace("text_to_replace", " ")
     print(new_line)
```

when i print it to check if it was done, i can see that the lines are as they were before. no change was made.

can anyone help me to find out why?

Comment: you are passing "text_to_replace" as string not variable!

Answer (score 1):

> each line starts with the very same string which i want to delete.

The problem is you're passing a string `"text_to_replace"` rather than the variable `text_to_replace`.

But, for this specific problem, you could just remove the first *n* characters from each line:

```
text_to_replace = "Chart: Bar Backtest: NQU8-CME [CB]  1 Min   #1 | Study: free dll = 0 |"
n = len(text_to_replace)

for each_line in siera_log:
     new_line = each_line[n:]
     print(new_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you quote a variable it becomes a string literal and won't be evaluated as a variable.

Change your line for replacement to:

```
new_line = each_line.replace(text_to_replace, " ")
```